# Performance of com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer and HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, http, ssl, https, httpserver

I developed a HTTP proxy which makes HTTPS->HTTP conversion, using `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer` and `HttpURLConnection`. Unfortunately it can process only 5 little HTTPS POST request per second. All other requests can't connect to proxy.

I have apache with SSL + tomcat on the same server and it process 50 HTTPS request/sec. Tomcat without apache process 50 HTTP request/second to, so apache with SSL don't slow him at all. If i use my `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer` it slows tomcat 10x times! I use it in such way:

```
HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(config.getInPort()), 0);
server.createContext("/https", new HttpProxyHandler(config));       
server.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(SSLContext.getDefault()));
server.setExecutor(null);
server.start();
```

Handler only send received request to another http URL via `HttpURLConnection`.

Why the performance of `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` is so bad? Is any performance statistic of `HttpsServer` available? I need very performance server. What if i just read request from SSL socket and write to TCP socket? Will it be suitable for HTTPS request processing?

Comment: `I need very performance server.` so you need awesome network and process power

Comment: The `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer` is only a toy. If all you're doing is proxying you should look at an existing proxy solution such as Apache Squid. Using an HTTP server as a proxy is going to add lots of latency.

Comment: We already have ssl->tcp proxy so we want to extend it functionality with https->http. I try now to set executor, performance increased, but i see a lot of errors in jmeter. Can i just make HTTPS->HTTP proxy on the SSL->TCP level? What if just read from SSL and write to TCP, will it work for HTTP?  Which existing easy to use parformance http proxy you recommend?